# Android Soundboard Help

Tags: android

Someone is making a simple soundboard for me but when I try it on the emulator, it loads very slow(10+ seconds), and every sound that is longer than maybe 4 seconds gets cut off. The person mentioned that he is using SoundPool. Anyone know what is wrong and what might fix it?

Comment: I would suggest that you have the someone who is making it for you post a question, so that they can provide technical details regarding there implementation, including code samples.  You don't provide enough information there to say anything.

Comment: Ok thanks I will try and suggest that to him.

Answer (score 0):

Generally, Emulators are much slower than real devices.
I created a soundboard with soundPool and sounds were very slow and lagging on emulators while on my Samsung Galaxy S2 it was perfect !!
Try running it on real device